# Codeigniter dropdown default to last item?

Tags: codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I create an array of numbers for ordering a gallery. I wanted to know if there was a way to have the dropdown default to the last item instead of the first? So with the example code when the page loads it would have the 6th element (value 5) selected as default.

```
<php? // Codeigniter that generates the select dropdown.
form_dropdown('order', $order);
?>

<select name="order">
    <option value="0">1</option>
    <option value="1">2</option>
    <option value="2">3</option>
    <option value="3">4</option>
    <option value="4">5</option>
    <option value="5">6</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your update, I am assuming you want to achieve the result below with the `CodeIgniter` `form_dropdown()` function?

```
<option value="5" selected="selected">6</option>
```

What you would have to do is add a few parameters to the function like this:

```
echo form_dropdown('order', '', '5');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
form_dropdown('order', $order, 5);
```

Check [form_dropdown](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html) in CI's userguide for this

If you want to fetch the last element dynamically then use [end()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) and [key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) functions to fetch the key of the last element of the array.
So here goes the code.

```
form_dropdown('order', $order, key(end($order)));
```